# Is it possible to create an Android AlertDialog without a border?

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, border, android-alertdialog

I'd like to an AlertDialog that has no border. Currently all AlertDialogs on my 2 phones have borders, with the borders looking different on each phone. I'm guessing this is due to manufacturer customization.

I know I can use a standard Dialog for more control, but hope to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [Android Borderless Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883425/android-borderless-dialog)

A custom xml layout for the dialog should do the trick :)

Comment: That link shows how to use a Dialog instead of an AlertDialog. I'm specifically looking to use an AlertDialog.

Comment: You could create a custom dialog that looks like an alert dialog. That's what I'd do, it's not too much hassle :)