# Android: Fullscreen Dialog not really full screen

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog

I am creating a Dialog like this:

```
 dialog = new Dialog(Start.this);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.wait);
 dialog.setTitle(null);
 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
 getWindow().setLayout( metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels);
 dialog.show();
```

But it is not really full-screen, it has that dialog edge around it. Is there a way to completly set it to full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the very first question in the related section on the right, you'll see this question: [Android Borderless Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883425/android-borderless-dialog). It answers your question. You want to use a different theme instead of the default dialog theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().setLayout( metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels);
```

is wrong, you need to set the Window of Dialog, not the Activity. like this:

```
dialog.show();
dialog.getWindow().setLayout( metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels);
```