# Fill whole screen scrollview android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a problem to fill the whole screen with a scrollview.

How do I make the scrollview cover the whole screen width and screenheight? I tried with **fillviewport** but that that works for the screenheight.

I am not sure if its the scrollview or its parent (FrameLayout) that is the problem?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="img1"/>

 <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/text_img1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:visibility="gone"
     />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="img2"/>

 <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/text_img2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:visibility="gone"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="img3"/>

 <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/text_img3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:visibility="gone"
    />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @BartoszLipinski - yes - android.app.AlertDialog

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<ScrollView>` from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`.

Example:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
```

Also, [you should be using `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` in API 8+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent).

**EDIT:**

After talking a bit in the comments, OP and I discovered that the FrameLayout's default background is transparent, which means you can see the old view underneath.

Using a `LinearLayout` or really anything instead of a `FrameLayout` will fix this problem.

Comment: @java Interesting. Is there any particular reason why you're using a FrameLayout? Try changing it to a LinearLayout, or try setting a background color for the FrameLayout.

Comment: Yes - you are correct, I have just been thinking of this. I'll try to change that (clumpsy of me - I can see now that Android Lint tells me the FrameLayout or ScrollView is useless.

Comment: @java Excellent! I'm glad I could help you figure this out. I'll update my answer and I would appreciate it if you could accept it as the correct one so that future developers who see this question will see that we found how to resolve it. :)

Comment: Yes I will if it works, but the same warning if I use LinearLayout as parent

Answer (score 0):

change your `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` like this

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Thanks, but no success

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are going in the right direction but your main problem is probably due to the fact that it's a `Dialog`.

First of all make sure your `Dialog` is borderless. You can use one of approaches proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883425/android-borderless-dialog) (not to duplicate answers).