# Progressbar in Android without border

Tags: android, progress-bar

How to create a progressbar without border?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863493/progressbar-dialog-without-border

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<style name="my_style" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null
</item>
</style>
```

From this similar thread: [ProgressBar dialog Without Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863493/progressbar-dialog-without-border)