# Using custom ProgressDialog android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am using custom `ProgressDialog` in my application, I am able to make it custom but I also want to remove the upper border or window of `progressDialog`.
In `styles.xml` I define `customDialog` as

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">#7BC047</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
     <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
</style>
```

For removing the parent window I am setting `windowBackground` to null and `windowFrame` to null but it did't work for me.
Currently my custom progress dialog look like that in the image given below[image]

I am using this code to set the style of `progressDialog`.

```
 private void showProgressDialog() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this,R.style.CustomDialog);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in. Please wait.");
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

So,help me regarding this issue any help should be really appreciated.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3948347/1102014).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This answer does not address the problem stated in the question, but when searching for how to implement a custom progress dialog, this is the only link pointing to SO. That said, I found a cool and easy-to -use custom progress dialog by a certain `Maksym Dybarskyi` on this [link](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1743).

**All Credit goes to the creator, not me.Am just sharing**

All you need to do is add this to your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
...
   compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
}
```

And then the custom style:

```
<style name="Custom" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog">
    <item name="DialogTitleAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="DialogTitleText">Please Wait</item>
    <item name="DialogSpotColor">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="DialogSpotCount">8</item>
</style>
```

Finally, in your code do this:

```
private AlertDialog progressDialog;
progressDialog = new SpotsDialog(mContext, R.style.Custom);

//Am using it in an AsyncTask. So in  my onPreExecute, I do this:
public void onPreExecute() {
  super.onPreExecute();
  progressDialog.show();
  ...
 }

//dismiss in onPostExecute
public void onPostExecute(){
   progressDialog.dismiss();
 }
```

Result:

[image]

**The yellow dots move from left to right and you can change the number of dots in styles**

Comment: Is there any way to change background of alert dialog by using this library?

Comment: Yes. @GuruprasadRao check Khawar's answer below

Comment: `<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>` add this is style

Comment: do not forget to add the following to Proguard , otherwise the dots will not appear in the signed APK
`-keep class dmax.dialog.** {
    *;
}`

Answer (score 17):

I know I'm quite late to answer but I'll answer any way,

```
Dialog dialog = new  Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_login);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm using custom `ProgressDialog` in my application .
For that we have to follow some steps this are as follow.

**step-1**
Create a xml layout `custom_progress.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/dp_size_10"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**step-2**
Create a java file for this custom dialog.

```
package com.example.customeprogress;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class CustomProgressDialogue extends Dialog {
    public CustomProgressDialogue(Context context) {
        super(context);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = getWindow().getAttributes();

        wlmp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp);
        setTitle(null);
        setCancelable(false);
        setOnCancelListener(null);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.custom_progress, null);
        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

**step-3**
Create a object of this custom class in your activity java class and initialised 
it as follow use the object for `show()` or `dismiss()`

> CustomProgressDialogue object=new CustomProgressDialogue(this);

and show this dialog using.

> object.show();
>   and dismissed it using 
>   object.dismiss();

Result of output.
[see out put here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5OBQ.png)

Comment: Thank you @Deepak gupta

Comment: This is the exact solution i was looking for. It also helps managing height and width of Alert dialog. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just check for using activity name in your constructor of progress dialog,

```
 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this,R.style.CustomDialog);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this on style

```
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>

<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: Your answer seems to trivial. Please be more descriptive on what you proposing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `CustomDialog` in `styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
```

And this `style`:

```
 <style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle" >
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
   <item name="android:background">#7BC047</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorTransparent</item>
</style>
```

This did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a suitable answer for the above question. But this is interesting and I thought to add here.

(I cannot comment with my current reputation)

Check this [link](https://medium.com/mindorks/stop-implementing-the-default-loading-dialog-in-you-android-apps-43c3a85036d6)

The original author is adding a gif instead of default loading dialog and I think 
if there is an improvement then it would be nice replacement.

Comment: Please add content of link to your answer

Comment: I already added it. Does it not visible to others.. :| [LInk](https://medium.com/mindorks/stop-implementing-the-default-loading-dialog-in-you-android-apps-43c3a85036d6)