# I am calling multiple webservices one by one on upload. In this case I am unable to interect with app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

My problem is that when I call first webservice I am showing ProgressDialog with please wait... message. In this case I cant do other event like click or other.
I have to wait until all webservices  completed.

I want to call multiple web services in single activity. But I want to show progress bar in top right corner like android g+ app and many other apps. In this manner I cant interect with app.

Please could you provide me a perfect solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single question have multiple answer.

```
I want to show progress bar in top right corner like android g+ app and many other apps
```

For above your query you have to use **custom progress dialog**.There are many resource available on web to make custom Dialog.

[See Example & Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910028/using-custom-progressdialog-android)

```
Next, I call first webservice I am showing ProgressDialog with please wait... message. In this case I cant do other event like click or other.I have to wait until all webservices completed.I want to call multiple web services in single activity.
```

For this query you have to **manage Thread** or **asynctask task** so you will manage your web service.

[See Example & Reference](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Comment: Thanks. Can you forward me link by which I can get understanding ?

Comment: i have update some link. and if its help full you then accept it.