# how to remove a background of custom progress dialog

Tags: android

iam making a custom progress dialog

my custom style code is

```
 <style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
 <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
 <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
 </style>
```

and my java code is.

```
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context,R.style.CustomDialog);
    pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pDialog.setMessage("Processing");

    pDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
```

now how i  remove a bckground color in my progress dialog same is 
image link is [Using custom ProgressDialog android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910028/using-custom-progressdialog-android)

Comment: You know the question you linked is not yet answered. Maybe your answer will come from it when resolved?

Answer (score 3):

in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

in your code:

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
```

Comment: thanks very much but now progress dialog appears on the top i want it appears on the middle of the scree.

Comment: pDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

Answer (score 2):

Just use this in your style

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Credits to Sir SC