# How to create loading screen in android?

Tags: android, progress-bar, loading, customdialog

I am developing an android app, in which I need a loading screen like the one given below. In this screen I want a custom progress bar and a loading text in the centre of the screen, and the background effect should be blurred. When the loading starts, the user should not be able to perform any action.

[image]

How can I create this type of loading screen?

Comment: What have yo tried so far ?

Comment: Not very clearly something you want. For loading bar will suffice any appropriate View.
To lock user environment will be enough any View on all the elements. (coarse resolution)
But background downloading resources absolutely other conversation.

Answer (score 2):

**@Ganpat Kaliya**

Please check [Transparent progress dialog on Android](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-transparent-progress-dialog-on-android/)

Just set

```
setTitle(Loading...);
```

Comment: This is fine and working. can you give me hint to set progress bar and title "loading" both of in one line means horizontally ?

Comment: and also how to display progress bar in small size in this example ?

Comment: @GanpatKaliya Its progress dialog not progress bar

Comment: I konw but I wont small size progress icon and I manage this but what about title and icon both in horizontal layout and center in screen ?

Comment: "I wont small size progress icon" did you try my link properly .Actually it works fine in here

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the custom Progress dialog. The purpose of using progress dialog is that as you wanted the screen to be blur, so when ever you would bring Progress dialog to front the activity would get blur , additionally it is highly customize able , you can do what you want.

A very useful explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910028/using-custom-progressdialog-android) and [here](http://islandofatlas.net/2014/03/29/android-custom-progress-dialog.html). please check them out and apply.

Comment: It Is display dialog what I don't need. only progress bar and loading text.

Comment: you can set the background of the dialog to the transparent which will give the same result as you wanted , if you also want to hide the title it can also be achieved , I cant see that you can not customize it as you wanted. it is really very easy