# Include a splash screen in the middle of an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap, imageview, splash-screen

I have developed an application to click or select images from gallery and count the number of objects present in the image. For larger images, the processing is taking a while (10 to 15 seconds). The application looks like its frozen over this period. Here is the work flow of my application

Main Screen (blank screen with a button to move to next screen) -> Second screen (with a navigation drawer and a fragment). This fragment holds my ImageView. A button in the second screen my main drawer. The button is responsible for the start of processing. When ever the user clicks on this button, the processing starts and after a while the morphed image will be set to the image view and an alert dialog displaying the count will appear. So, in the onClick method, I will retrieve the image from image view and do the processing by calling some classes. After it is done I am setting the ImageView with the morphed Bitmap.

So, I would like make a call to the splash screen with text like "processing" after the image is retrieved and i want to hide this screen as soon as the bitmap is returned back from my other class. Then the morphed image is loaded to the image view. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create loading screen in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439145/how-to-create-loading-screen-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

> The application looks like its frozen over this period. Here is the work flow of my application

Any time consuming tasks should be executed in background (be it `AsyncTask`, `IntentService` or others). If needed. block the UI from user interaction, but do NOT **make it blocked**. UI thread must be responsive and 10-15 secs is a lot.