# Transparent, borderless ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I've got a `ProgressDialog` that I have positioned to the bottom of my screen as to not overlap a logo. What I would like to do is create a custom style for the `ProgressDialog` that removes the background and the border. I'm not having any luck here.

Does anyone have a clue on how to apply this style?

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried setting the background to a transparent color?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225889/how-to-center-progress-indicator-in-progressdialog-easily-when-no-title-text-pas/3226233#3226233) gives a detailed code sample.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if I just style an out of the box ProgressDialog, it simply ignores the styles. I'll try to extend my own custom dialog and see if that'll do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an image for progress dialog and customize as you wish like-

```
         // Custom position Of image Loader
          WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp =
          pDialog.getWindow().getAttributes(); int height =
          getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels; wmlp.y =
          height/4; pDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(wmlp);
```

For more details please follow the link below:

http://androiddubd.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-create-transparent-progress.html

Answer (score 2):

This can help you (worked for me):

Create a layout in res/layout, like this (named, for example, as progressbar.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progressBar"
      style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, put this code in your Activity or Fragment:

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

// the first parameter (this) is your activity
// ... but if you need to use this code in a Fragment, use getActivity() instead 
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,null,null);  
progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
```

So, the ProgressDialog will to show without background and border.