# Android: How to Change ProgressDialog's Text Color?

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-theme

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transparent, borderless ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291978/transparent-borderless-progressdialog)

I'm using `Theme.Light` in my app. While using `Progress Dialog`, text of dialog color is black and it's not encouraging.

I tried this change only dialog's text color, but didn't work:

```
<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Do I have to set the style (MyDialog) in any XML? Or how can I change dialog's text color?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Apply your custom theme in ProgressDialog constructor:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.Theme_MyDialog);
```

also change `<item name="android:textColorSecondary">*my_text_color*</item>` in this theme. In my case it's work on emulator and Acer LicuidE, but Samsung Galaxy Mini don't want to set my custom color for text((.

Comment: I could only make it work using `<item name="android:textColor">*my_text_color*</item>`.