# Positionning the spinning wheel in a custom progress dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm using the custom progress dialog given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225889/how-to-center-progress-indicator-in-progressdialog-easily-when-no-title-text-pas/3226233#3226233), which as the style shown below. The spinning wheel is centered, and I can't find how to set a custom position to it.

Anybody can help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="NewDialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>    
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **ProgressBar** in your layout . You can place it any position you want in your screen.

```
<ProgressBar android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"              
                android:id="@+id/showProgress"/>
```

Comment: I need a spinning wheel of default size with a transparent (say #50000000) background filling the parent. If I set android:layout_width and android:layout_height to `fill_parent` in a ProgessBar, I get a huge spinning wheel. According to the link I provide in my question it can only be done with a custom dialog. The only problem is that the wheel is centered, and I'd like to set a custom position. Have you got an alternative solution?

Comment: you can see this link. I have added the code in my blog. http://sujitdroid.blogspot.com/2011/10/custom-progressdilaog-like-iphone.html