# Custom Progress Dialog Animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I am working on `Custom Progress Dialog`. I've set its style like done in this SO question [Positionning the spinning wheel in a custom progress dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738490/positionning-the-spinning-wheel-in-a-custom-progress-dialog) My progress dialog is showing no animation at all. When I changed the `background` to `black` then it was only showing a black box. I want my progress dialog to animate.

In activity I am doing something like this

```
 public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.NewDialog);
    }
```

and the NewDialog is as:

```
<style name="NewDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:width">50dip</item>
    <item name="android:height">50dip</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>
```

Any help is appreciated in advance

Comment: Post the **specific code** relevant to the animation

Comment: i copy paste the code from <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225889/how-to-center-progress-indicator-in-progressdialog-easily-when-no-title-text-pa>

Comment: Don't make us have to go to another post to have to see the code, post ONLY the **RELEVANT** code to the animation.

Comment: In activity i am doing this                                      public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
         super(context, R.style.NewDialog);
     }

Comment: I have tried this code it is perfectly working . Do you want me to post the whole code ? I dont understand why it is not showing animation ?

Comment: yes plz @SALMAN i would be thankful to you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.animation.Animation;

public class MyProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

    public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context,R.style.NewDialog);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

//RESOURCE STYLE FILE res->values->mydialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="NewDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:width">600dip</item>
    <item name="android:height">100dip</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

//AND USE THIS CODE ANYWHERE IN YOUR APPLICATION TO GET CUSTOM PROGRESS DIALOG

```
MyProgressDialog pd = new MyProgressDialog(YouActivity.this);
pd.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
pd.show();
```

Well there isn't any difference in your code and mine as I have run your code just to test whether you are experiencing any problem or not  but still I am posting for you so that you can sought out the problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: one little difference @SALMAN I was extending MyProgressDialog with Dialog, and in your case its ProgressDialog. Still having an issue the progress dialog is not centred in the box it is lying, any clue

Comment: Change these two lines in style file.                                                   <item name="android:width">20dip</item>
<item name="android:height">20dip</item>

Comment: Salman: i want something like in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225889/how-to-center-progress-indicator-in-progressdialog-easily-when-no-title-text-pa   the progress indicator is not in the center of the dialog

Answer (score 2):

```
public class TransparentProgressDialog extends Dialog {

 private ImageView iv;

 public TransparentProgressDialog(Context context, int resourceIdOfImage) {

     super(context, R.style.TransparentProgressDialog);
  WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = getWindow().getAttributes();
  wlmp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
  getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp);
  setTitle(null);
   setCancelable(false);
   setOnCancelListener(null);
   resourceIdOfImage = R.drawable.loading_spinner_icon;
  LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
   layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  iv = new ImageView(context);
  iv.setImageResource(resourceIdOfImage);
  layout.addView(iv, params);
  addContentView(layout, params);
  }

  }
```

You  will get complete example with animation [HERE](http://shortcutsandroid.blogspot.in/2015/02/custom-progress-dialog-with-animation.html)