# AsyncTask progress wheel not spinning?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, swipe

AsyncTask work fine when I'm doing **zip** , **unzip** , **download file** and **store data from XML into database**.

But now I'm trying to implement https://github.com/fry15/uk.co.jasonfry.android.tools swipe in layout(data pick from database and show in webview) which add layout in run time so it takes a long time so I can put this in AsyncTask but now AsyncTask progress wheel not spinning ?

My code is working properly but problem is not spinning wheel on AsyncTask.

```
public class LoadSlideAndQuestion extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DialogBoxOnClick.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Slide and Questions...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

        Intent i = new Intent(DialogBoxOnClick.this, SlideScreen.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

**SlideActivity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.temp);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    width = display.getWidth();
    topic = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("name").toString();
    fetchdata();

    PageControl mPageControl = (PageControl) findViewById(R.id.page_control);
    mSwipeView = (SwipeView) findViewById(R.id.swipe_view);

    mSwipeView.setPageControl(mPageControl);

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        mSwipeView.addView(new FrameLayout(this));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {

        ((FrameLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(i))
                .addView(setupView());
        count++;
    }
}
```

**setupView()  function which returns views**

```
    public View setupView() {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflator = getLayoutInflater();
    LinearLayout childlayout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflator.inflate(
            R.layout.webview, Switcher, false);

    question_number = (TextView) childlayout
            .findViewById(R.id.question_number);
    question_type = (TextView) childlayout.findViewById(R.id.question_type);
    question_parameters = (TextView) childlayout
            .findViewById(R.id.question_parameter);
    question_correct_answer = (TextView) childlayout
            .findViewById(R.id.question_correct_answer);
    question_difficulty = (TextView) childlayout
            .findViewById(R.id.question_difficulty);
    newObject = new Questionclass();
    newObject = XmlHandler.questionlist.get(count);
    System.out.println(newObject.QUESTION_NUMBER + "   NEW OBJECT");

    questionView = (WebView) childlayout.findViewById(R.id.Que_View);
    WebSettings webSettings = questionView.getSettings();
    // webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
    webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(23);

    question_number.setText(newObject.QUESTION_NUMBER);
    question_type.setText(newObject.QUESTION_TYPE);
    question_correct_answer.setText(newObject.QUESTION_CORRECT_ANSWER);
    question_parameters.setText(newObject.QUESTION_PARAMETERS);
    question_difficulty.setText(newObject.QUESTION_DIFFICULTY);

    questionView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    questionView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    questionView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    questionView.clearView();
    questionView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
            "",
            IntegralParse.htmlParse(newObject.QUESTION_CODE,
                    "/mnt/sdcard/CHECK_LESSON_QUESTIONS/" + topic + "/" + topic
                            + "/" + newObject.QUESTION_NUMBER,
                    getApplicationContext(), width)
                    + "<hr/>"
                    + IntegralParse.htmlParse(newObject.QUESTION_SOL_CODE,
                            "/mnt/sdcard/CHECK_LESSON_QUESTIONS/" + topic + "/"
                                    + topic + "/"
                                    + newObject.QUESTION_NUMBER,
                            getApplicationContext(), width), "text/html",
            "utf-8", "");
    questionView.requestLayout();
    return childlayout;

}
```

Comment: Try making clear what your actual question is, what your code is that is related to the question and not sending people around to libraries they might not even know.

Comment: a litle code snippet is always helpful..

Comment: @Puru now I'm edit my question...

Comment: @StefandeBruijn now im edit my question???

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to manipulate the UI outside of the UI thread?
You need to use a [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to queue tasks for performing on the UI thread from a background thread.

More information on [Communicating with the UI thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html).