# how can i create a very simple animated image / progress bar on android device?

Tags: android, progress-bar, animated-gif, indicator

i am doing some processing in the background in my app and i am in need to show a small indicator what the app is retrieving data from the server. in a perfect world i would use an animated gif but since google decided not to support it i need a solution. i don't want the build-in dialog box that prevents the user from using an app. i need to be able place it anywhere on my layout and show/hide it when i need to. my app runs on 2.2+

any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ProgressBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).

Comment: thanks but i don't want to show progress, i need to show that something is "going on" :)

Comment: @android-developer: Correct. Use `ProgressBar` in indefinite-progress mode. Or, use a `RotateAnimation` on an `ImageView`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704295/android-show-an-indeterminate-progressbar-without-the-dialog