# Android - How to make a progress dialog embedded on the UI?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I know that I have found the answer to this question on StackOverflow one day but I couldn't find the link anymore. Basically, I want to create a `ProgressDialog` that doesn't block the  UI, like the one from the Android Market:

[image: Non blocking ProgressDialog]

Any idea?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: The pattern is known as [`ProgressWheel`](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/progress-wheel)

**EDIT2**: Just to make it clear, until now I have used the `ProgressDialog` class and I am not doing this in XML. What I am doing looks like this:

[image: ProgressDialog]

Comment: It's quite unclear what you *really* want. In that case you want to remove the `ProgressDialog`; where do you want the indeterminate `ProgressBar` to be?

Comment: The issue is not whether my Progress`Thing` needs to be indeterminable or not. It's more a styling issue. Right now I have a `ProgressDialog` that is shown in front of the activity. I want to make it embedded on the UI. I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704295/android-show-an-indeterminate-progressbar-without-the-dialog. So yes it involves using a ProgressBar instead of ProgressDialog.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I misunderstood your question a bit. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`android:indeterminate="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android%3aindeterminate) from [`ProgressBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).

Sample code:

```
<ProgressBar 
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```